# first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

How I can make the following sentences in first order logic as a set of Horn ?.

"The Martians are not informatics appreciate anything more than a computer."

"The Martians informatics appreciate anything more than a slow computer."

"There are fast and slow computers."

I have deduced the following predicates:

or (/ 1) -> multiplicity 1-- be a computer

i (/ 1) -> multiplicity 1 - be an informatic

l (/ 1) -> multiplicity 1 - be slow

m (/ 1) -> multiplicity 1 - be Martian

a (/ 3) -> multiplicity 3 - a (X, Y, Z) --- "X" to appreciate more "Y" to "Z"

Comment: A **basic Horn formula** is a *disjunction* with at most one non-negated literal. A **Horn formula** is a *conjunction* of basic H-f. How you manage quantifiers ?

Comment: Quantifiers are eliminated once they have transformed sentences Skolen type, you can eliminate the existential quantifiers, but not how to express sentences in first-order language. The translation is the first step then would have to transform horn clauses. You know Prolog? 
Prolog uses resolution by refutation, sentences are transformed horn clauses and the question refuses to have negative clause.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Consider the sentence :

> There are fast and slow computers.

We can translate it as :

> $∃x(Computer(x)∧Fast(x))∧∃y(Computer(y)∧Slow(y))$.

We have that :

- a **basic Horn formula** is a disjunction with at most one non-negated atomic formula
- a **Horn formula** is in prenex form and its matrix is a conjunction of basic horn formulae.

Thus, it is enough to rewrite the above formula in prenex form :

> > $\exists x \exists y(Computer(x)∧Fast(x)∧Computer(y)∧Slow(y))$.

The matrix is a conjunction of basic Horn formulae, because every conjunct is a disjunction (with a single formula) with at most one non-negated atomic formula.